# 3 different root states for ui-router angular + laravel 5.1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, laravel-5.1

I am developing using laravel as backend and angular as client.

in my app i have 3 laravel views: admin.blade.php, employer.blade.php, employee.blade.php

in each of these blade.php views i have angular set with `ng-app` and `<div ui-view=""></div>`

this is my configuration:

```
   $stateProvider


    .state('admin', {
     url: "/",
     templateUrl: '../partials/db/manager.html',
     abstract:true
    })

    .state('admin.tables', {
      url: "^/tables",
      controller: 'TController',   
      templateUrl: '../partials/db/tables.html'  
    })
    .state('admin.stats', {
      url: "^/stats",
      controller: 'TController',   
      templateUrl: '../partials/db/stats.html'  
    })
    .state('admin.tables.type_user', {
      url: "/type_user",
      controller: 'TController',   
      templateUrl: '../partials/db/table.html',

    })
    .state('admin.tables.sys_param_values', {
      url: "/sys_param_values",
      controller: 'TController',   
      templateUrl: '../partials/db/table.html'  
    })
    .state('employer', {
      url: "/employer",
      controller: 'UserHomeController', 
      templateUrl: '../partials/employerHome.html'      
     })
     .state('jobseeker', {
      url: "/jobseeker",
      controller: 'UserHomeController', 
      templateUrl: '../partials/userHome.html'      
     });
```

everything is working kind of ok, the problem is for example - the `<div ui-view=""></div>`  in `employer.blade.php` isnt supose to allow the `admin` states.

how can i resstrict all `admin` states to `admin.blade.php` and all employer states to `employer.blade.php`

Comment: Can't you split the states in 3 different files and include the correct states with each php-file?

Comment: please explain again. im sorry, didnt understand exactly..sounds like the simple solution i looked for@loddn

Comment: what did you mean by split the states to different files?

Comment: @loddn i did split app.js with the ui-router config to 3 different app1/2/3.js

Comment: in employer.blade.php you include a file  the employer-states and in admin.blade.php you incluide a file with the admin-states